# How do I safely open, work on, and close many shape files in pyQGIS?

Tags: qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I have a pyQGIS script that loops over many files (>1000). I had been getting a mix of `OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files` and `Creation of layer failed (OGR error: Failed to open Shape DBF file`

I think I must not be closing out files correctly and leaving something orphaned behind so I wrote the following and consistently get the dbf file error after opening saving and closing a file about 122 times. I'm not sure if the dbf error relates to the Too many files open error but it would seem a likely starting point on the road to also solving that problem.

How can I safely: open, work on, save, close and repeat?

I can cut and paste the following code into the pyQGIS terminal to illustrate the problem, so you can too presumably

```py
import tempfile
def delete_shape(shape_path):
    nosuff=os.path.splitext(shape_path)[0]
    suffix_list=['.shp','.shx','.dbf','.prj','.sbn','.sbx','.fbn','.fbx','.ain','.aih','.ixs','.mxs','.atx','.shp.xml','.cpg','.qix','.qpj']
    for suffix in suffix_list:
        try:
            os.remove(nosuff+suffix)
        except Exception as e:
            pass

def copyover(Afilename,Bfilename):
    delete_shape(Bfilename)
    Alayer = QgsVectorLayer(Afilename, "A file", "ogr")
    write_error, error_string = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(Alayer, Bfilename, "system", QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(epsg), "ESRI Shapefile")
    if write_error != QgsVectorFileWriter.NoError:
        print('WARNING write error no. '+str(write_error)+', was: {details}'.format(details=error_string))
    Alayer = None


###################################
## Create simple test shape file ##
###################################
low_lon=0; low_lat=0; high_lon=10; high_lat=10
epsg=4326
bboxlayer=QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=epsg:"+str(epsg)+\
"&field=id:integer&field=name:string(20)&index=yes",\
"bbox_polygon","memory")
bbl_dp = bboxlayer.dataProvider()
bboxlayer.startEditing()
bbox_feature = QgsFeature()
bbox_feature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY( [ [ \
QgsPointXY(low_lon,low_lat),QgsPointXY(low_lon,high_lat), \
QgsPointXY(high_lon,high_lat),QgsPointXY(high_lon,low_lat) ] ] ))
(res, outFeats) = bboxlayer.dataProvider().addFeatures([bbox_feature])
bboxlayer.commitChanges()
Afilename=os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(),"Afile.shp")
write_error, error_string = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(bboxlayer,\
Afilename, "system", QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(epsg), "ESRI Shapefile")
if write_error != QgsVectorFileWriter.NoError:
    print('WARNING write error was{details}'.format(details=error_string))

bboxlayer = None
Bfilename=os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(),"Bfile.shp")

##############################
## open save and close loop ##
##############################
for x in range(200):
    print(x)
    copyover(Afilename,Bfilename)
    copyover(Bfilename,Afilename)
```

It seems that pushing the work to a subprocess will solve it as per: [force-garbage-collection-in-python-to-free-memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32167386/force-garbage-collection-in-python-to-free-memory) but this doesn't tell me why or how to solve it without using a subprocess which is much slower and may have caveats that cant be solved in my wider use case.